# Display iCloud sync status to user

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, icloud

I am using Core Data and iCloud sync setup with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. When the user opens the app on a second device for the first time, it takes some time before the iCloud fetches all the data from the cloud. I would like to show to the user that iCloud sync is in progress with ProgressView().

I tried the following code:

```
import Combine
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

class CloudSyncManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSyncing: Bool = false

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification)
            .sink { [weak self] notification in
                guard let self else { return }

                if let event = notification.userInfo?[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventNotificationUserInfoKey]
                    as? NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.Event
                {
                    let sync = event.type == .import || event.type == .export || event.type == .setup
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isSyncing = sync
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                            self.isSyncing = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

With this code, the `isSyncing` is set to `true` at the very end of the sync process (last second or two) while console shows that work is being done for much longer. Is there any way to notify the user "sooner"?

Comment: `Is there any way to notify the user "sooner"?`, Sooner than when? sooner than
 when the iCloud sync is setup? Or is your question about how to display
 a ProgressView()?

Comment: Sooner = when iCloud starts the setup. iCloud starts the set up already during app startup and prints logs into the console. This takes approximately 30-40 seconds. There are no events coming from the NotificationCenter for neither import, export or setup event types during this time. First notifications are received at the very end of the sync only.